# Picklist formula with OR condition

Tags: formula, picklist

I want to create a formula field (Value__c) where I have to display 4 different texts (A, B, C, D) depending on another picklist field's value. I am trying to add an OR condition on my formula but its not getting saved. My picklist field (Score__c) has 16 values. (1,2,3,4......,16). I want to create formula which shows me the result that If I choose 1,2,3 or 4 it display A on Value__c field, if I choose 5,6, 7 or 8, display B and so on... I have chosen Formala Return type as 'Text'. Here is my formula which is not getting saved.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Score__c, "1" || "2" || "3" || "4"),"A",""), IF(ISPICKVAL(Score__c, "5" || "6" || "7" || "8"),"B",""), IF(ISPICKVAL(Score__c, "9" || "10" || "11" || "12"),"C",""), IF(ISPICKVAL(Score__c, "13" || "14" || "15" || "16"),"D","")
```

Comment: Or try "OR" instead of "IF" and get rid of all the || ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula. Not sure the way you are using the `OR` logic there.

```
IF(
    (ISPICKVAL(Score__c, "1") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"2") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"3") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"4")),"A",
    IF((ISPICKVAL(Score__c, "5") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"6") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"7") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"8")),"B",
        IF((ISPICKVAL(Score__c, "9") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"10") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"11") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"12")),"C",
            IF((ISPICKVAL(Score__c, "13") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"14") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"15") || ISPICKVAL(Score__c,"16")),"D",""))))
```

Comment: Pleasure to help you.Cheers!